# Matrix and vector multiplication returns wrong result using GLM

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have this equation with constant **c** and vec4 **x**=(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4):

x_1*c + x_2*c + x_3*c + x_4*c

where sum(x_i) = 1

That means, the result should be c:

=(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4) * c

= 1 * c = c

So I have a vec4 and a matrix4*3 multiplication like this:

(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) *
((? c ?),
(? c ?),
(? c ?)
(? c ?)
)

However, the y coord in result (vec3) is not equal to c at all.

How is that and how to fix it?

```
float constant = 10.0f;
glm::vec3 v1 = glm::vec3(48.0f, constant, 18.0f);
glm::vec3 v2 = glm::vec3(56.0f, constant, 18.0f);
glm::vec3 v3 = glm::vec3(56.0f, constant, 12.0f);
glm::vec3 v4 = glm::vec3(52.0f, constant, 8.0f);
glm::mat4x3 M = glm::mat4x3(v1, v2, v3, v4);
glm::vec4 sumTo1 = glm::vec4(0.2f, 0.4f, 0.1f, 0.3f);
glm::vec3 result = sumTo1 * M;
cout << "sumTo1=" << glm::to_string(sumTo1) << endl;
cout << "M=" << glm::to_string(M) << endl;
cout << "result=" << glm::to_string(result) << endl;
```

Output:

```
sumTo1=vec4(0.200000, 0.400000, 0.100000, 0.300000)
M=mat4x3((48.000000, 10.000000, 18.000000), (56.000000, 10.000000, 18.000000), (56.000000, 10.000000, 12.000000), (52.000000, 10.000000, 8.000000))
result=vec3(15.400001, 17.000000, 16.400000)
```

To my knowledge the vector is considered as a row vector already.

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Comment: Your math is just wrong. You are multiplying a 4d row vector with a `3x4` matrix which isn't even defined mathematically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL matrices and [GLM](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/index.html) matrices are stored in column major order. The vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the right:

<s>`glm::vec3 result = sumTo1 * M;`</s>

```cpp
glm::vec3 result = M * sumTo1;
```

---

See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)
and [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 5.10. Vector and Matrix Operations](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#vector-and-matrix-operations)

> The exceptions are matrix multiplied by vector, vector multiplied by matrix, and matrix multiplied by matrix. These do not operate component-wise, but rather perform the correct linear algebraic multiply.
>
> ```c
> vec3 v, u;
> mat3 m;
> u = v * m;
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```c
> u.x = dot(v, m[0]); // m[0] is the left column of m
> u.y = dot(v, m[1]); // dot(a,b) is the inner (dot) product of a and b
> u.z = dot(v, m[2]);
> ```
>
> And
>
> ```c
> u = m * v;
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```c
> u.x = m[0].x * v.x + m[1].x * v.y + m[2].x * v.z;
> u.y = m[0].y * v.x + m[1].y * v.y + m[2].y * v.z;
> u.z = m[0].z * v.x + m[1].z * v.y + m[2].z * v.z;
> ```

Comment: doesn't it contradict this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863952/10976041

Comment: @Ecto Please respect the specification. I've extended the answer and add the specification of vector and matrix multiplications.

Comment: @Ecto "doesn't it contradict this answer?" no it doesn't. That answer gives explictely the example of `mat2x4*vec4` being invalid while `vec4*mat2x4` being valid. But what you attempt here is `vec4 * mat4x3`, which isn't valid, while `vec4*mat3x4` would be valid.

Comment: @Eco: glm can automatically transpose vectors. Which means that you can treat vectors either as row or as column vectors. But it doesn't transpose the matrix for you. vec4 * mat4x3 (vec4 as row-vector) is not a valid operation. mat4x3 * vec4 (vec4 as column-vector) is.

Comment: @BDL: "But it doesn't transpose the matrix for you." Even if it would do that, the transposed operation `mat3x4 * vec4` would be as invalid as the starting point `vec4 * mat4x3`.

Comment: @derhass: Correct. But `vec4 * mat3x4` would be the valid calculation op is looking for. What op actually calculates is `vec3 * mat4x3` (leaving away the z-component of the vector), then casting the resulting vec4 into a vec3. E.g.: `17 = 56*0,2+10*0,4+18*0,1`

Comment: exactly, the equation was actually more complicated (multiple matrixes) and because I didn't find an easy way to transpose glm::vec3 I just wrote it like that.

Comment: @Ecto: You didn't write it like that. You wrote `vec4 * mat4x3` which is not the same as `vec4 * mat3x4`.

Comment: it was vec4 * mat4 * mat4x3.

Comment: @Ecto: Doesn't matter. `mat4 * mat4x3` is still not a valid matrix multiplicaton. The number of rows of the first matrix has to match the number of rows of the second. #columns(mat4) = 4, #rows(mat4x3) = 3. No match -> no valid multiplication. Are you confused because the traditional mathematical form is `rows x columns` but glsl uses `columns x rows`?